# How can I change a value taken from the array without modifying the array itself?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to extract a value from this array and use it inside a variable.  but then if I log array I see the user one now is Julian. How do I avoid it?

```
let array = [{'id':'1','name':'User one','phone': '+51 111 222 333'},'id':'2','name':'User two','phone': '+51 111 222 333'}, 'id':'3','name':'User Three','phone': '+51 111 222 333'}];
```

I do:

```
 let user = array[0];
 user.name = "Julian"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to copy the object so it has it's own reference in memory so you can use Object.assign to create a new Object

```js
let array = [{'id':'1','name':'User one','phone': '+51 111 222 333'},{'id':'2','name':'User two','phone': '+51 111 222 333'},{ 'id':'3','name':'User Three','phone': '+51 111 222 333'}];

   const ob=Object.assign({},array[0])
   ob.name="Julian"
   console.log(array)
```

alternatively you can use the spread operator

```js
let array = [{'id':'1','name':'User one','phone': '+51 111 222 333'},{'id':'2','name':'User two','phone': '+51 111 222 333'},{ 'id':'3','name':'User Three','phone': '+51 111 222 333'}];

   const ob={...array[0]}
   ob.name="Julian"
   console.log(array)
   console.log(ob)
```

Comment: I tried but I got an error: `78:21  error  "ob" is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: It should work without variable declaration. However I have updated that, try it now and let me know if it works for you

Comment: It does. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...` to create a  "duplicate" of the object that can be modified without changing the original.

Remember that `array` contains references to objects. By doing `let user = array[0]`, you are assigning `user` to the same reference as `array[0]`. Both point to the same object, and changes done through one can be seen with the other. However, by using `...`, you can put all the key-value pairs from the object stored in `array[0]` into a new object that can be modified independently.

```js
let array = [
  {'id':'1',
  'name':'User one',
  'phone': '+51 111 222 333'
  },
  {'id':'2',
  'name':'User two',
  'phone': '+51 111 222 333'
  }, 
  {
  'id':'3',
  'name':'User Three',
  'phone': '+51 111 222 333'
  }
]


let user = {...array[0]}
user.name = "Julian"

console.log(user)
console.log(array[0])
```

Comment: This is working on my laptop but not on my phone, its old, maybe thats why. Thanks

Comment: Strange. The phone being old is a likely explanation, the spread operator was introduced in ES6. Glad it worked though!